# How to write Interfaces in c#? Rules for name of Interface?

Tags: c#, counter, performancecounter

In one of the requirement (custom performance counters for my application) i am writing Interfaces first, but i am not sure whether i am writing proper name as per Interface guildeline. I used plural and use verb, please verify and suggest

```
interface ICreateCounters
{
    bool CreateCategories(Categories objCategories) {}
    bool CreateCounters(Counters objCounters){}
}

interface UseCounters
{
    Increment()
}
```

Please advice?

Is there any existing library available?

Comment: There are no Rules, only Naming Guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: No `{}` after a method of an interface, all interface names should begin wtih I, so `IUseCounters`, `Increment()` should have some return value type (`void`?).

Comment: in your case something like `ICounterFactory`

Comment: I'll add that sometimes even Microsoft doesn't follow its guidelines... Right mr. `System.Runtime.InteropServices._Type`? (it's an interface, it's used for example by the `Type` class) :-)

Comment: `I used plural` So your `Counters` class contains *multiple* counters, right?

Comment: In my experience, it's more common for interface names to describe what interface implementers can do rather than what they are. Example: IIncremantable is the interface for things that can be incremented. Names Always start with capital 'I' followed by the rest of the name, which also starts with a Capital.

Comment: Often, it looks/reads better if interface's name is "I...able", e.g. interface IIncrementable {Increment()}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hemant sir,
There are no explicit rules for an interface, but in Microsoft all the interfaces do start with capital letter 'I'.

The name that follows the letter 'I' should start with capital letter and words should describe the meaning and work.

In your case may be use IIncreementalCounter or ICounterOperation instead of UseCounters.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question is :

Microsoft hase [performance counter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) So if this fits your needs use this

Comment: What's this got to do with naming conventions for interfaces?

Comment: @Gareth : Its has to do with his second question : Is there any existing library available?

Comment: Thanks, But why i am looking custom class library is because i am maintaining my categories, counters and Instance in database. Also i am maintaining whether single or multi Instance and based upon that i am creating counters. I feel i have to write my own custom one.